# Sorting sentences in alphabetical order

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of sentences I want to arrange in alphabetical order in Python. However, sometimes the sentences begin with a quotation mark.

I have tried the .sort() method on Python, but it sorts all the sentences that begin with quotation marks together in alphabetical order and then sorts the non-quotation mark sentences.

sentences.sort()

The desired results should be a list where all the sentences are arranged in alphabetical order even though some might begin with punctuation marks.

Comment: Only quotation mark ? Or is there any other `chars` as well ?

Comment: mostly quotation marks but one occurrence of "--" character before the start of the sentence.

Comment: What have you tried so far to mitigate the quotation mark?

Answer (score 2):

Use the whole string as sorting key if it starts with an alphanumeric character, cut the first character otherwise:

```
data = ['abc', '"efg"', 'def', "'aaa'"]

sorted(data, key=lambda s: s if s[0].isalnum() else s[1:])
# ["'aaa'", 'abc', 'def', '"efg"']
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want :

```py
sorted(iterable, key=lambda s:s.strip('"\''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all special characters and spaces from the beginning of strings in the list before sorting:

```
import re
data = ['? abc', '" efg"', '  def   ', "'aaa'"]
print(sorted(data, key=lambda s: s if s.isalnum() else re.sub(r"^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", '', s)))
```

This accounts for the case where there is more than one special character at the beginning of the string, or a special character followed by a space.

Output:

```
["'aaa'", '? abc', '  def   ', '" efg"']
```

Comment: @AshleyAshok Since my answer worked for you, please consider marking it as accepted (check mark on the left).